# Update for Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

There is an update for Windows 8.1  [(KB 2919355).](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-is/windows-8/install-latest-update-windows-8-1)
Does Windows Server 2012 R2 have its own update with similar features? I cannot seem to find any information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Update is the same for Windows 8.1 and Server 2012 R2:

*Windows RT 8.1, Windows 8.1, and **Windows Server 2012 R2 Update: April 2014***
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2919355/en-us

Here is a document which explains what is new for Server 2012 R2:

**Windows Server 2012 R2 Update**
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn645472.aspx